# Reference for Comprehensive Prophecy Analysis in Scripture?

Tags: church-history, prophecy, reference-request, scriptures

**What all resources/expositions/writings have been published as a comprehensive analysis of prophecy in Scripture?** Any resources about prophecy in all of Scripture, its fulfillment, extrabiblical support, etc. would be helpful. I would think that 2000 years of church history would already have a few of these, especially since prophecy and miracles seem to be the favorite apologetic for the truth of Christianity, especially for the early church.

I have heard and seen several claims about the number of prophecies in the Bible, such as "over 1000+ fulfilled prophecies!" or "2000 different prophecies!" or I even read a claim of 3000 prophecies in Scripture. I don't like relying on sources I don't trust and I wanted to do a more thorough analysis, so I got 2 books that were proposed to be a comprehensive exposition on "every prophecy/prophetic passage in the Bible" and a book on every Messianic prophecy.

- *The Prophecy Knowledge Handbook: All the Prophecies of Scripture Explained in One Volume* by John Walvoord ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0896935094))
- *Exploring Bible Prophecy from Genesis to Revelation: Clarifying the Meaning of Every Prophetic Passage* by (editors) Tim LaHaye and Ed Hindson ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0736948031))
- *All the Messianic Prophecies of the Bible* by Herbert Lockyer ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0310280915))

A basic meta-analysis of the two comprehensive resources shows a noticeable discrepancy in [what is accepted as prophecy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9406/what-is-the-biblical-definition-of-prophecy). I found that they disagreed on the number of prophecies at the book-level (meaning # prophecies in each book of the Bible) by 269 prophecies in just the Old Testament. The LaHaye book only includes 374 total prophecies in the Old Testament, so this difference represents a significant percentage of total prophecy. The LaHaye says that it "focuses on the unfulfilled prophecies" though it still claims to be comprehensive, discussing "every prophetic passage in the Bible." I would be even more interested in the fulfilled prophecies than the unfulfilled ones. The Messianic prophecy book doesn't even give a specific number of prophecies besides "over 300"; in fact, the first two books don't either, but I just counted them by hand. For example, I counted 659 sections/subsections of prophecy in LaHaye though it claims there are over 1000 predictive prophecies. I recognize that identifying exact numbers of prophecies can be difficult and blurry, such as when you include typologies or other things like that, but **I would think there should be multiple analyses in the past that have been produced on prophecy in Scripture.**

I would especially be interested in references that address the questions

1. What is the prophecy/prophetic claim?
2. Has it been fulfilled?
3. Is its fulfillment recorded in Scripture?
4. Is there extrabiblical support of this prophecy?

I am not interested in answers giving specific examples of prophecies that have or have not been fulfilled. **I am only interested in publications (books, academic journals, church fathers, theologians, etc.) that extensively discuss the prophetic aspect of Scripture in an approximately comprehensive way**, since prophecy is important enough to account for about 1/4 of all Scripture. I have actually seen 2 sets of 5 criteria that were created by atheists for analyzing prophecy that I actually find quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

> What all resources/expositions/writings have been published as a comprehensive analysis of prophecy in Scripture?

The "comprehensive" requirement is unsatisfiable, since the works of God are [ongoing](https://biblehub.com/amos/3-7.htm) and the spirit of prophecy reveals things [line upon line](https://biblehub.com/kjv/isaiah/28-10.htm) to mankind after we are prepared to receive them. I take your qualifier "approximately" to mean that sincere effort is made towards being thorough, and not that every conceivable ramification or typology is anticipated.

> I don't like relying on sources I don't trust and I wanted to do a more thorough analysis

Prophecy can be understood clearly if interpreted correctly. We are reminded that the Savior spoke in parables to inhibit the understanding of the unfaithful on the one hand, and to edify the righteous and give them opportunity to exercise faith on the other hand. Therefore we should not expect that all things are tidily understood without faith and revelation, nonetheless the saving truths are plain to be understood and universal in their meaning:

> We have also a more sure word of prophecy; whereunto ye do well that
> ye take heed, as unto a light that shineth in a dark place, until the
> day dawn, and the day star arise in your hearts:
> Knowing this first, that **no prophecy of the scripture is of any
> private interpretation.** (2 Peter 1:19-20)

Commentary on Scripture is not worth much compared to Scripture itself, unless the commentary is also Scripture, as in the case of prophets quoting one another and expounding, of which there are many examples in the Scriptures. The only way you could find an explication worthy of pursuit is to find someone who has the spirit of prophecy himself. Otherwise his commentaries will be mere [speculation](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/2-Timothy-4-3/) and [opinion](https://biblehub.com/1_corinthians/2-14.htm), and completely [lacking](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews%205%3A4&version=KJV) [authority](https://biblehub.com/matthew/7-29.htm). Peter's testimony continues:

> For the prophecy came not in old time by the will of man: but holy
> men of God spake as they were moved by the Holy Ghost.

Consistent with this understanding, the best resources I can refer you to include over 180 years of prophecy and accompanying explanation that identify modern applications, past, present and future fulfillments, additional corroboration and indeed extra-biblical support to the prophecies made in the Bible, including the translation and revelation of some [contemporary accounts](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/gs/book-of-mormon?lang=eng) that [corroborate](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/bofm/1-ne/13.39?lang=eng), [further specify](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/bofm/2-ne/10?lang=eng) and even [fulfill](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/ot/isa/29?lang=eng) Biblical prophecies.
God continues to call Prophets today as He has in the past, with a mantle equal to Moses's.

**These discourses** have been painstakingly compiled and translated into perhaps more languages than any other modern theological material I am aware of:

https://archive.org/details/conferencereport (includes much of the 1800s-1970)
https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference?lang=eng (1970-present)

While I cannot guarantee that these resources are "comprehensive" per the above constraint, they are collectively *the most thorough, relevant and accurate resource on the subject* that I can vouch for. I believe that [God will yet reveal many great and important things pertaining to His kingdom](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/friend/2015/08/article-of-faith-9?lang=eng), and so what has not yet been explicated or fulfilled we have reason to expect will be done in the future. Moreover these discourses uniquely satisfy  the requirement of accurate analysis, in that the givers have the spirit of prophecy themselves. The reader is forewarned that the purpose for which these discourses were given and written is not to appease academicians, but rather to increase faith in Jesus Christ and accomplish His work, which worldly scholars have an unfortunate habit of categorizing as unsatisfying, despite it accomplishing the very purpose of Scripture. But then we already knew by the testimony of Scripture that the worldly man and the man of Christ are opposites.

A relevant and repeated prophecy made in the Bible alludes to [a future day when all hidden things shall be revealed](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2012%3A2-3&version=KJV). In sum, the "comprehensive" analysis of prophecy does not exist yet because there are things not yet revealed.

[Side note: the church has close to 6000 years of Earthly history, as it goes back to Adam and Eve, and Christianity is the only religion to hold this distinction. It is the oldest religion in the world. The fact that we obtain most of the accounts through Moses despite his forbears having kept records themselves and clearly having worshiped Christ strongly suggests that what we have in the Old Testament has been abridged, and numerous ancient prophetic accounts may have been lost. The structure of the church apparently changed from patriarchal to apostolic with the coming of Jesus Christ, but the religion is identical.]